# cant insert into data base with php insert using pdo

Tags: php, pdo

```
<?php
$user=htmlspecialchars($_POST['user']);
$password=htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
$email=htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
//$number=htmlspecialchars($_POST['number']);
$quater=htmlspecialchars($_POST['quater']);
if (isset($user) && isset($password)&& isset($email ) && isset($quater ))
    {
      try{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=library;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO user(name, password, email,  quater ) VALUES(?,?,?,? )');
$req->execute(array('name'=> $user,'password'=>$password,'email'=>$email,'quater' => $quater));
}
    else
    {
        echo "<p color=red >please fill all the  fills above<p>";
    }
?>
```

get the following error

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in [...}

Answer (score 2):

You're using different kinds of placeholders here.

When using `?` as the placeholder, you bind without names and in the proper order. If you're using named placeholders (e.g. `:name`), the order doesn't matter, but the key in the array must match the named placeholder.

So your two options are to

1. Use named placeholders (which I think is easier to read)
2. Remove the indexes in your execute-array

So, with **alternative one** would look like

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO user (name, password, email, quater) VALUES (:name, :password, :email, :quater)');
$req->execute(array('name'=> $user, 'password' => $password, 'email' => $email, 'quater' => $quater));
```

Notice that I've replaced all the placeholders, from `?` to a named one, `:name`.

**Alternative two** would look like this

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO user (name, password, email, quater) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
$req->execute(array($user, $password, $email, $quater));
```

Here you'll see that the placeholders are still `?`, but the keys are removed in the execute-array.

*You could use keys here, but they'd have to be 0-3 (as they are assigned default by PHP).*

Reference

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: its still give these same error after correcting it